# java.util.NoSuchElementException when iterating over a list

Tags: java, iterator

Following is a method that is iterating over a list:

```
@Override
    public void DataRowMapper(List<?> list) {
        Iterator<UserModel> i = (Iterator<UserModel>) list.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            this.setUserID(i.next().getUserID());
            this.setUserName(i.next().getUserName());
        }
```

Now the problem is that when I run the debugger I see that i.hasNext() is having the correct values but still I keep getting NoElementException. Another surprising thing I have seen is that previously I was able to get the UserID printed on Console but just the UserID, rest of it was null but soon after I started getting this error. There is no issue at all with the database. I am 100% convinced that I am getting the right results because I see it in the debugger but for some reason I cant get past through this error in the normal mode. Class UserModel is a simple POJO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are calling i.next twice in the loop which will move the record pointer to next element.get the reference to element with a single call to i.next.

so it should be like

```java
while (i.hasNext){
    usermodel curr =i.next;
    curr.username;
    curr.userid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, it worked! I guess I didn't realize that I was making double calls to i.next.